# class undefined property in php

Tags: php, class, pdo, undefined, prepare

maybe this is a possible duplicate, i have search here some questions like this but i have tried all the answers, but i still got this error

```
Notice: Undefined property: User::$_pdo in D:\xampp\htdocs\pengun\classes\DB.php on line 32
```

and this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\pengun\classes\DB.php on line 32
```

this is my DB class

```
<?php
class DB {

    private $_pdo, $_query, $_result, $_count, $_row;

    public function __construct($host, $dbname, $user, $password) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;

        try {
            $_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->user, $this->password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        $_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function select($fields, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=','>','<','>=','<=');

            $column     = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table} WHERE {$column} {$operator} {$value}";
                if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                    $this->_query->execute();
                    $this->_row = $this->_query->fetch();

                    print_r($this->_row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can someone please tell me what is the problem with my code? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because in constructor, you are assigning `new PDO` just to local variable accessible only inside constructor. You have to use:

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->user, $this->password);
...
$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: And if you (just for testing purpose) try `prepare()`, `execute()` and `fetch()` in constructor right after new PDO instance is created, does this error appear too here?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigned `PDO` object to local variable in constructor. You must set class variable!

Change

```
$_pdo
```

to

```
$this->_pdo
```

in lines 13 and 18.

Comment: Please write your error here. That should work well.

Comment: i've already posted it, look on my question that is the error

Comment: Are you add another constructor in `User` class?